# Python3 Syntax with boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i am creating a script using python and boto3 to start a aws machine with the settings i want and for it to create a apache webserver, part of the project is to edit the default apache webpage.

So i have everything set up and running, and currently editing the webpage to include a picture from an s3 aws bucket. One problem i am having is that i cant get the syntax quite right to automatically ssh in and put the HTML code into index.html. The code i have is correct but i cant figure out the syntax as it uses many quotes.

Heres a variable for the string. It is mainly the sudo echo part im struggling with, not the ssh, as the SSH works.

```
cmd5 = "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i assignment1.pem ec2-user@" + publicIP + " sudo echo '<image src = \"https://dylanbucket250199141112.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image.jpg\"> </image>' >> /var/www/html/index.html"
```

Heres the subprocess im using.

```
subprocess.run(cmd5, shell = True)
```

Comment: How does your problem relate to boto3?

Comment: Doesn't directly, it is just part of the project im using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to forgo the quotation issue, you can use this format for modifying the file:

```
echo '<image src = "https://dylanbucket250199141112.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/image.jpg"> </image>' | ssh ...
```